# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, fractions

How to calculate the following limit?
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \Big(1+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\Big)^{\frac{x^2-1}{2}\cdot\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}}=e^{\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x^2}{x^2-1}}=e^2$$

Answer (score 4):

it's the same as that of
$$
\left(\frac{1+1/n}{1-1/n}\right)^{n}
$$
Without the bottom, this gives $e$ as is well known.

$(1-1/n)^{-1} = 1+ 1/n + 1/n^2 +...$

multiplying we get

$$
(1 + 2/n + O(n^{-2}))^n
$$
If we drop the $O$ term we get $e^2.$

it simply remains to show that the final error disappears in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that, as $u \to 0$, by the Taylor series expansion, we readily have
$$
\begin{align}
e^u& =1+u+\mathcal{O}(u^2)\\
\ln (1+u)&=u+\mathcal{O}(u^2)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
x^2\ln \left(1+\frac {2}{x^2-1}\right)=x^2 \left(\frac {2}{x^2-1}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac {1}{x^4}\right)\right)=2+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac {1}{x^2}\right)
$$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2}&=\Big(\frac{x^2-1+2}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2}\\\\
&= \left(1+\frac {2}{x^2-1}\right)^{x^2}\\\\
&=e^{\large x^2\ln \left(1+\frac {2}{x^2-1}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\large 2+\mathcal{O}(\frac {1}{x^2})}\\\\
&\to e^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice, but I doubt the OP knows about Big O notation.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I could have used simpler arguments, but I think this is just another approach I wanted to show, if I'm allowed to ;).

Comment: Sure, it's just that in my opinion you could explain what that notation means in the first place. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using L'Hopital's rule this way:

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \exp\ln\Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2} &= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \exp x^2\ln\Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big) \\ &= \exp \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)-\ln(x^2-1)}{x^{-2}} \\ &= \exp \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x(x^2+1)^{-1}-2x(x^2-1)^{-1}}{-2x^{-3}} \\ &= \exp \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^4(x^2+1)-x^4(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)} \\ &= \exp \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x^4}{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)} \\ &= e^2
\end{align}$$

It's permissible to swap the $\exp$ with the $\lim$ between lines one and two because the exponential function is continuous, and L'Hopital's rule is applied between lines two and three.

Comment: The proof is correct and the downvote is incorrect *unless* it was done for **other** reason, yet the downvoted didn't bother to explain. G Tony, you should perhaps remark that l'Hospital was done between the second and the third line, and maybe dropping that exp all along could help to make it even clearer. +1

Comment: I teach this subject fairly often, and I find that keeping the $\exp$ all along is useful for many students. Working out a side problem, and then having to remember to exponentiate at the end seems to confuse some people. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we know the definition of $e$ as $\displaystyle e=\lim_{x\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty }\Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{2}{x^2-1}\Big)^{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{y\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{2}{y}\Big)^{y+1}\\
&=\lim_{y\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{2}{y}\Big)^{1} \times \lim_{y\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{2}{y}\Big)^{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{1}{y/2}\Big)^{y}\\
&=\lim_{t\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{1}{t}\Big)^{2t}\\
&=\Big[\lim_{t\to \infty }\Big(1+\frac{1}{t}\Big)^{t}\Big]^2\\
&=e^2.
\end{align}
Note: $y=x^2$ then later $t=y/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the property that: $e = lim_{x\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{x})^{x}$

$lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{2} - 1})^{x^{2}}$ = $lim_{x\to\infty} (1 + \frac{2}{x^{2} - 1})^{x^{2}}$ = $e^{lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x^{2}}{x^2 - 1}}$

= $e^{2}$

Answer (score -1):

The qty in bracket tends to 1 as x→infinte and power tends to infinity u can easily prove that Lt(x→a){f(x)}^(g(x)) if f(a)→1 and g(a)→∞ then its equal to limit of e^(f(x)-1)*(g(x)) as x→a so here it is.. e^(2/(x^2-1))*(x^2) limit as x→ ∞ giving e^2 .. !

Comment: If you don't use MathJax to write mathematics here, in particular answers, is pretty unlikely they will get read by many members and, as in this case, the answer may even be downvoted, though I think this is uncalled for in this case. Read the following http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Thanks man.. !  Will use mathjax ahead.