# Solve limit $\lim _{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{5-x^3}{1-x^3}\right)^{2x^2+1}$.

Tags: limits

I would be grateful if you choose this limit. It is desirable to complete solution. Thanks you.
$$\lim _{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{5-x^3}{1-x^3}\right)^{2x^2+1}$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203005/calculate-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left-fracx-2x2-right3x and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061142/evaluate-lim-x%E2%86%920-left-frac1-tan-x1-sin-x-right1-x2/1061152#1061152

Comment: take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168828/find-lim-x-to-infty-left-fracx21x2-1-rightx2/1168885#1168885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write:
$$\left(\frac{5-x^3}{1-x^3}\right)^{2x^2+1}=e^{(2x^2+1)\ln\left(\frac{5-x^3}{1-x^3}\right)}=e^{(2x^2+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{1-x^3}\right)}$$
and
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{1-x^3}\right)\sim\frac{4}{1-x^3}\ \ \ \ (x\rightarrow \infty)$$
Therefore
$$e^{(2x^2+1)\ln\left(\frac{5-x^3}{1-x^3}\right)}\sim e^{(2x^2+1)\left(\frac{4}{1-x^3}\right)}\sim e^{\frac{8x^2}{-x^3}}=e^{-\frac{8}{x}}\rightarrow e^0=1$$